# What should I use as a base for my wall mounted PC case?

Tags: electrical, walls, mounting, custom-cabinetry

Here is an example of what I am trying to put together:
[image]

What material could I use as a base onto which I can mount the motherboard, hard-disk and other wiring?

Comment: This is my first post here, so do let me know how I can improve it so it meets the requirements mentioned in the FAQ section.. Thanks

Comment: This question is very close to being off topic, since it's not exactly dealing with "home improvement". It does, however, sort of have to do with building materials, so it may hold up.  It seems there tends to be a lot of confusion around the "DIY" label, were people tend to think anything done yourself is on topic.  The reality is, we only focus on Do-it-yourself home building and repair.  Don't be surprised if this question is closed or migrated.

Comment: @Tester101 Aha I thought so too.. But where could/would it get migrated too..? Ideally we need a site for DIY from scratch projects.

Comment: If you feel another site is needed, you could always propose one on [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I have created a [meta discussion for it](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/744/what-makes-the-below-question-off-topic-and-ideally-which-site-should-this-be-mi)..

Comment: Interesting look, if you're into that -- but this could really benefit from some [split-loom tubing](http://www.parts-express.com/pe/showdetl.cfm?partnumber=080-527) or [hook-and-loop cable wrap](http://www.cableorganizer.com/pet-wrap/) (no affiliation or endorsement, just convenient links).

Answer (score 2):

Your circuitry and peripheral devices could be mounted on a piece of plywood. Such plywood could be pre-painted if you wished to get a desired color effect. For a more unique effect you could cover the plywood with a layer of sheet cooper similar to that used by roofers. This could look very cool of it was all buffed out to an exquisite shine and sealed with a coating to keep it from tarnishing. A clear lacquer finish may be just the ticket.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan Michael, thanks. I will also have to consider whether it is safe/recommended to mount the electronics on a copper sheet. But I guess the coating would act as an insulation?

Comment: @KentPawar - About mounting electronics. Consider how a PC motherboard mounts in a computer chassis. The chassis is very conductive metal and the board is mounted on standoffs. Use the same idea for the copper mounting.

Comment: Yes, will do that. Is there any place I can get an explanation on what a standoff is ..? I googled a bit but it is not clear if it acts as an insulator..

Comment: @KentPawar [Standoff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standoff_(separator)).

Comment: @KentPawar - Mounting your motherboard over a metal surface is done with spacers placed under the board mounting holes that raise the board up off the metal surface. If the metal surface is GND the spacers can be metal and contact with the circular copper patterns around the mounting holes. These patterns are connected to GND in the circuit of the motherboard of PC style boards. For mounting to a plywood surface, whether you cover it with copper or not could be done with pan head screws and a tubular metal spacer or nylon spacer placed around the screw on the bottom side.